# How to shuffle files in @foreach using blade

Tags: laravel, loops, foreach, laravel-blade, shuffle

this is my code:

```
@foreach ($videos as $video)
        <a href="{{ $video['_meta']->url }}">
          <img class="vid" src="{{$video->thumbnail}}" onerror="this.src='/img/failed.png';">
        </a>
      @endforeach
```

And I've been reading all over the place, but can't find out how I can get the videos to come up in random order whenever they refresh.

What I tried:

```
@foreach ($videos->shuffle() as $video)
        <a href="{{ $video['_meta']->url }}">
          <img class="vid" src="{{$video->thumbnail}}" onerror="this.src='/img/failed.png';">
        </a>
      @endforeach
```

(added ->shuffle() after $videos), but that didn't work.

Comment: check it's collection or array , it will work only if `$videos` is laravel collection https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-shuffle

Comment: or if it is array then you can convert in to collection and then you can apply `shuffle()` function

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you are probably sending something like this:

```
$data =[..., 'videos'=> $videos,...];
return view('view', $data);
```

You can use php shuffle method here to solve your problem (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) like this:

```
$data =[..., 'videos'=>shuffle($videos),...];
return view('view', $data);
```

this should do it, I hope it helps.